# The href links in my html code won't work.

Tags: html, image, href

I wrote a simple web page in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="http://media.web.britannica.com/eb-media/59/89959-050-6CC4DDA1.jpg" alt="WorldMap" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="WorldMap" id="Map">
    <area alt="NorthAmerica" title="" href="www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="307,181,488,250" />
    <area alt="SouthAmerica" title="" href="www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="468,504,636,432" />
    <area alt="Europe" title="" href="www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="853,147,1005,180" />
    <area alt="Africa" title="" href="www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="964,350,826,383" />
    <area alt="Asia" title="" href="www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="1115,232,1221,193" />
    <area alt="Australia" title="" href="www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="1270,564,1483,532" />
    [...]
</map>


</body>
</html>
```

Which returns a map of the world, and should create a link for every continent.

However, the links do not respond to clicking.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Your `usemap="#WorldMap"` must match the `name` tag. Not the id.

Like this:

```html
<img src="http://media.web.britannica.com/eb-media/59/89959-050-6CC4DDA1.jpg" alt="WorldMap" usemap="#WorldMap" />
<map name="WorldMap" id="Map">
    <area alt="NorthAmerica" title="" href="/#" shape="rect" coords="307,181,488,250" />
    <area alt="SouthAmerica" title="" href="/#" shape="rect" coords="468,504,636,432" />
    <area alt="Europe" title="" href="/#" shape="rect" coords="853,147,1005,180" />
    <area alt="Africa" title="" href="/#" shape="rect" coords="964,350,826,383" />
    <area alt="Asia" title="" href="/#" shape="rect" coords="1115,232,1221,193" />
    <area alt="Australia" title="" href="/#" shape="rect" coords="1270,564,1483,532" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're linking to an off-site resource your links *must* contain an `http://` or `https://` prefix.

That means you need:

```
<area alt="NorthAmerica" title="" href="http://www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="307,181,488,250" />
```

Though presumably you'd make that a more specific link.

Comment: that's not the issue at hand thought... it would still be clickable and a hand cursor would appear regardless.